# How to set split size equal one line in Hadoop's MapReduce Streaming?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

**Goal:** each node, having a copy of the matrix, reads the matrix, calculates some value via mapper(matrix, key), and emits <key, value>

I'm, trying to use mapper written in python via streaming. There are no reducers.
Essentially, I'm trying to do the task similar to https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html#How_do_I_process_files_one_per_map

**Approach:** I generated an input file (tasks) in the following format (header just for reference):

```
/path/matrix.csv 0
/path/matrix.csv 0
...              99
```

Then I run (hadoop streaming) mapper on this tasks. Mapper parses line to get the arguments - filename, key; then mapper reads the matrix by filename and calculates the value associated with the key; then emits <key, value>.

**Problem:** current approach works and produces correct results, *but it does so in one mapper, since the input file size is mere 100 lines of text, and it is not getting split into several mappers.* **How do I force such split despite small input size?**

Comment: Why do you need it? Let's leave the decision to framework on number of mappers.

Comment: Please reread the problem statement. My input have to be small, because it only contains a file path and the key. The file would be big, but fits to memory of each machine. So I just need to run in parallel many machines on the same data with different key.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that instead of doing several mappers and no reducers I could do just the exact opposite. Now my architecture is as follows:

- thin mapper simply reads the input parameters and emits key, value
- fat reducers read the files and execute algorithm with received key, then emit results
- set -D mapreduce.job.reduces=10 to change the parallelization level

It was silly (mistaken) approach, but the correct one was not obvious either.